# Change edittype on addparam and editparam in JqGrid inline Navigator

Tags: jqgrid

I have two dropdowns in jqgrid inline navigator. I want to enable both dropdown only for add mode,and only one dropdown for edit mode.

```
grid = $("#gridTable");        
grid.jqGrid({
            colModel: [
                { name: 'empId' , width: "250",editable:true,edittype: 'select',editoptions:{value: {"Emp1","Emp2"}}, formoptions:{ rowpos:1, label: "Emp Id", elmprefix:"(*)"},editrules:{required:true}},
                { name: 'Address' , width: "250",editable:true,edittype: 'select',editoptions:{value: {"Emp Add1","Emp Add2"}}, formoptions:{ rowpos:2, label: "Address", elmprefix:"(*)"},editrules:{required:true}}                                        
            ],
            pager: '#gridTablePager',
            colNames:[ 'empId', 'Address'],
            rowList:[10,20,50,100,200,500],
            datatype: "jsonstring",
            datastr: dataInDb,
            jsonReader: { repeatitems: false },
            viewrecords: true,
            height: 300,
            ignoreCase: true
        });
```

What code I should add for this?

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like this.

```
 grid.jqGrid('inlineNav', "#" + paginator, {
  addParams: {
           addRowParams: {
             url: baseUrl + 'Plantilla/InsertCaracteristicaPlantillaTemp',
             mtype: "POST",
             oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                        InitModel(rowid, 'I');
             }
            },
            editParams: {
                url: baseUrl + 'Plantilla/UpdateCaracteristicaPlantillaTemp',
                mtype: "POST",
                oneditfunc: function (rowid) {
                    InitModel(rowid, 'U');
                }
});


function InitModel(rowid, Operation){

    if(Operation == "U")
       $("#" + rowid + "_fielName").attr("disabled", true);
}
```

Now, with that function you can enable and disable fields when you want.